# Why MongoId models change its object_id on loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, objectid

**The stage:**

A class including MongoId:

```
class Mission

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  attr_accessor :distance

  # ... other atts and methods ...
end
```

**The problem:**

In `Rails c`:

```
$ missions = Mission.all # => get all missions
$ missions[0].object_id # => 70264434234840
$ missions[1].object_id # => 70264410073940
# (for this example I will use only 2 records)
# Now look their object_ids on this loop:
$ missions.each {|m| puts m.object_id} # => 70264350130200, 70264359017780
# Second test with this example again:
$ for m in ms do puts m.object_id end # => 70264374331020, 70264374320260
```

The `object_id` isn't the same inside and out of the loop, and is different between both loops too. So if `distance` attribute is set inside a bucle, out the bucle its value is `nil`.

**Aditional Information:**

ActiveRecord and MongoId: This loop problem only occurs with MongoId, I tested the same example with ActiveRecord and the object_ids are the same inside and out the loop.

**My deduction:**

Each time `object_id` is called, a different value is returned. ***I guess MongoId makes a new database query whenever a mission is instanced (`missions[0]`), without using the instance inside the `missions` is collection (Mongoid::Criteria)***

**Questions:**

1. Why this happens? every explanation is welcome :)
2. How can iterate its "MongoId objects" preserving the same mission instance inside and outside of loop? (as ActiveRecord do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say this:

```
missions = Mission.all
```

you're just story a query in `missions`. Then each time you access the query, Mongoid will access the database:

```
missions[0] # One database access
missions[1] # Another database access
```

If you want to work with an array of Mongoid model instances, then say so:

```
missions = Mission.all.to_a
```

Of course that can create a lot of `Mongoid::Document`s so you need to be sure that that's what you want to do.

Normally you wouldn't care what the `object_id`s were, you'd compare the Mongoid objects directly (i.e. `obj1 == obj2`) or look at their `id`s instead of their `object_id`s.

Comment: Thanks @muIsTooShort, you are my hero! :) .. I understand the difference between `object_id` vs `id`, it was just for explain the example. Thank you.